# Where to put the mutex in a logging class?

Tags: c++, linux, queue, mutex

First off, it's been a while since I've used any sort of mutex or semaphore, so go easy on me.

I have implemented a generic logging class that right now only receives a message from other classes and prepends that message with date/time and the level of debug, and then prints the message to stdout.

I would like to implement some sort of queue or buffer that will hold many messages that are sent to the logging class and then write them to a file.

The problem that I'm running into is I can't decide how/where to protect the queue.

Below is some pseudo-code of what I've come up with so far:

```
logMessage(char *msg, int debugLevel){
    formattedMsg = formatMsg(msg, debugLevel) //formats the msg to include date/time & debugLevel
    lockMutext()
    queue.add(formattedMsg)
    unlockMutex()
}

wrtieToFile(){
    if (isMessageAvailable()) { //would check to see if there is a message in the queue
        lockMutext()
        file << queue.getFirst() //would append file with the first available msg from the queue
        unlockMutex()
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Do I really need to use the mutex in both places?
- Is a mutex really what I'm looking for?
- I'm thinking I may need a thread for the writing to the file part - does that sound like a good idea?

FYI I looking for a way to do this without using Boost or any 3rd party library.

**EDIT** The intended platform is Linux.

**EDIT 2** Moved formatMsg to before the mutex lock (thank you @Paul Rubel)

Comment: If the queue where u are storing the messages can be accessed by different classes simultaneously and randomly and your queue is common then you will need mutex or semaphores. If this is the scenario then acquire a mutex lock just before writing message to queue and release it once you are done. you will also need this while writing to the file ie acquire lock before writing and release it once you are done writing a message.

Comment: Are queue.add and queue.getFirst guaranteed nothrow? (The first is very unlikely.) If not, your lack of lock_guard or equivalent will leak the lock in the case of an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With respect to do you really need the mutex. Think what could happen if you didn't lock things. Unless your queue is thread-safe you probably need to protect both insertion and removal.

Imagine execution contexts changing as you are removing the first element. The add could find the queue in a inconsistent state, and then who knows what could happen.

Regarding creating the message, unless formatMsg makes use of shared resources you can probably more it out of the locked section, which can increase your parallelism.

Extracting the writing to file into its own thread sounds like a reasonable choice, that way the logging threads will not have to make the calls themselves.

Comment: So by putting the writting to file in another thread, this will alleviate calling threads from blocking? Or the calling threads will only block when they are adding a msg to the queue?

Comment: The logging thread will do the writing, work which your "Worker" thread won't have to wait for if it has non-logging work to do.  Calling threads will also have to block on insertion. One thing to keep in mind is that mutexes aren't necessarily "fair" so without work the order messages are inserted may not be the order in which they were generated.

Answer (score 1):

correct me if i'm wrong. Multiple callers from multiple threads all trying to access the same resource concurrently.

Maybe you could just have one mutex wrapping the entirety of your logging functionality.

watch out for race conditions.

**Edit**
Readers take a look at the comments to this answer for some valuable discussion

Comment: Multiple caller from multiple threads = yes. However, if I wrap all of the logging functionality in a mutex, won't that block the calling threads?

Comment: indeed, you will need to make those threads sleep until the resource is available

Comment: Is there a way to avoid blocking the calling threads? I'd like the calling threads to continue without having to wait for the logger to finish with its thing

Comment: well, i find it strange that you would want to: "hold messages that are sent to the logging class and then later write them to a file later", what happens if your process dies before logging has written to file?

Comment: I intend to handle signals and perform a dump of messages to the log file should the process "die"

Comment: I fixed my wording about the "then later write them" - I was trying to say that there would be a step between calling the logger and the msg writing to a file.

Comment: @redhotspike, the whole point of the queue is that you *don't* have to wait for the logger to finish its thing, that is, the costly write to disk.  You *may* have to block on the mutex before acquiring it but that is a small price.  In effect your threads are placing their garbage (log strings) at the curb (the queue).  Beyond that you don't care how long it takes the garbage men (your logging thread) to pick it up and haul it to the dump.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global variable which contains the number of element present in the queue or buffer. That means you need to `increment or decrement` this variable while `adding data` or `removing data` from buffer or queue. So you keep this variable inside a `mutex` for your above logging framework.

Comment: How would a global counter variable benefit if I used a queue? Can't I just check for not empty and then retrieve the first item?

Comment: You need have the limit(size) for the queue or buffer. If you have multiple process writing to the queue, Then in this case you need to have a lock on the variable which contains the number of item in the queue. Even when you are retrieving data from queue you need to decrement the value of number of items in queue. there can be situation when some process writing to the queue and you are also trying to retrieve data. This can result in deadlock. Using global counter you can restrict the read/write operation as well as store the current size of queue.

Comment: mohit, there is no need for a global ctr.  OP is presumably using std::queue which doesn't need a limit, it can grow on its own; and the ctr is implicit in queue.size().